# I only want to return users who where isactive = 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am still learning php - but I want to modify a working php page and check a MySQL table for isactive then only return users if it is set to 1.

The page originally said:

```
    foreach ($users as $U) {                
            if (!$U['name'])
                list($name) = explode('@', $U['default_email__address']);
            else
                $name = new UsersName($U['name']);
```

I tried this, but it isn't working:

```
    foreach ($users as $U) {
          
            if ($U->filter(array('isactive' => 1)));

            if (!$U['name'])
                list($name) = explode('@', $U['default_email__address']);
            else
                $name = new UsersName($U['name']);
```

and the rest of the page works fine. I am not sure if I should add my if statement at the top of the page, before the "foreach" or as part of the "foreach". I am not even positive I have correct way to pull the field value.

Comment: You don't have any statements in the `if` block.

Comment: Why don't you do the check in your SQL query? `SELECT ... WHERE isactive = 1`

Comment: The end value of `$name` may be a string or an object, this can be awkward and worth trying to make it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

`$U` appears to be an associative array. They aren't objects with methods. If you want to get `isactive`, just use `$U['isactive']`

```
foreach ($users as $U) {
    if ($U['isactive') {
        if (!$U['name']) {
            list($name) = explode('@', $U['default_email__address']);
        } else {
            $name = new UsersName($U['name']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add it to your table definition.

Comment: Thank you for the responses - the issue I am having is, there isn't anything looking at the table field to construct ['isactive']. I know I need to make 'isactive', it's where I build it, to be able to use your if statement, I am not sure of... I see all types of function builders in the class page, but there isn't anything building WHAT is looking at the table column field. I thought maybe I could do a manual lookup and say (basically) "Show me all users where user_account.isactive = 1. I am just not sure how to call it when it's baked into the array.

Comment: I just saw the "You need to add it to your table definition." I will look into seeing where to add it. Thank you.